# Получить информацию от элемента VBox. JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx

На странице имеется VBox, в приложении можно добавить элемент в этот VBox. Элементом будет являться карточка автомобиля, как на auto.ru. Что мне нужно: по нажатию на элемент VBox, будет открываться страница, содержащая данные из элемента, на который мы нажали. Как мне получить информацию от элемента VBox?

Добавление элемента в VBox

```java
AnchorPane pane = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("ad.fxml"));
vBox.getChildren().add(pane);
```

AdController

```java
private void setAutoElementInLKS() {
    try {
        DataBaseHandler dbHandler = new DataBaseHandler();
        ResultSet set = dbHandler.getAutoInfoForLKS();
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            set.next();
        }
        if (set.next()) {
            autoBrandModelLabel.setText(dbHandler.getBrandAndModel(set.getString(3)));
            bodyTypeLabel.setText(dbHandler.getTableInfo("name","body_type", set.getString(4)));
            transmissionLabel.setText(dbHandler.getTableInfo("name", "transmission", set.getString(5)));
            engineLabel.setText(dbHandler.getEngineInfo(set.getString(6)));
            driveLabel.setText(dbHandler.getTableInfo("name", "drive", set.getString(7)));
            regionLabel.setText(dbHandler.getTableInfo("name", "region", set.getString(8)));
            colorLabel.setText(dbHandler.getTableInfo("name", "color", set.getString(10)));
            mileageLabel.setText(dbHandler.getTableInfo("mileage","auto", set.getString(1)) + " км");
            yearLabel.setText(dbHandler.getTableInfo("year","auto", set.getString(1)));
            priceLabel.setText(dbHandler.getTableInfo("price", "auto", set.getString(1)) + " р");
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Обработчик клика есть, я не понимаю что в нем написать

```java
private void clickOnVBoxElement() {
    for (Node child: firstVBox.getChildren()) {
        child.setOnMouseClicked(mouseEvent -> {
                
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Абстрактный пример: окно с кнопкой и VBox, при нажатии на кнопку в VBox добавляется новая метка со случайным числом, и при создании же через лямбду привязывается обработчик нажатия. Лямбда имеет доступ к значению текста созданной метки (и вообще ко всем переменным метода, в котором она создана).

```
public class Controller {
    @FXML
    Button addItem;

    @FXML
    VBox vBox;

    private final Random random = new Random();

    @FXML
    void onActionAddItem() {
        String text = String.valueOf(random.nextInt(100));
        Label label = new Label(text);
        label.setOnMouseClicked(event -> {
            new Alert(Alert.AlertType.INFORMATION, "Текст: " + text).show();
        });
        vBox.getChildren().add(label);
    }
}
```

---

Более сложный пример:

Разделяем модель (информацию о машине), вью (панель отображения информации о машине), контроллер (всю логику). 100% чистоту реализации такого MVC правда не гарантирую :)

Наследуем панель отображения информации от AncorPane (или от любого другого контейнера), в конструктор передаем объект класса `Car` (в котором хранится все информация о машине, в примере ниже там только id, но можно добавить все нужные вам поля), внутри записываем во внутреннее поле, при клике по панели выводим значения из этого поля:

```
public class Controller {
    @FXML
    Button addItem;

    @FXML
    VBox vBox;

    private final Random random = new Random();

    @FXML
    void onActionAddItem() {
        Car car = new Car(random.nextInt(100));
        CarPane carPane = new CarPane(this, car);
        vBox.getChildren().add(carPane);
    }

    public void showCarInfo(Car car) {
        new Alert(Alert.AlertType.INFORMATION, "id машины: " + car.getId()).show();
    }
}
```

```
public class Car {
    private final long id;

    public Car(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }
}
```

```
public class CarPane extends AnchorPane {
    private final Controller controller;
    private final Car car;

    public CarPane(Controller controller, Car car) {
        this.controller = controller;
        this.car = car;

        getChildren().add(new Label("id машины: " + car.getId()));

        setOnMouseClicked(this::onClick);
    }

    private void onClick(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {
        controller.showCarInfo(car);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Сделал как обычно: через одно место.
Где добавляется информация объявления запоминал id автомобиля, далее ставил его в id pane

```java
AnchorPane pane = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("ad.fxml"));
pane.setId(AdController.getIdAuto());
firstVBox.getChildren().add(pane);
```